# new TextRecognizer.Builder(context).build() generates error

Tags: google-vision

I'm using [google vision sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples/ocr-reader) to create an OCR app, but statement

```
TextRecognizer textRecognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(context).build();
```

generates errors

> ```
> > E/native: jni_helper.cc:170 GetContents failed:
> > /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_vision/ocr/data/models/rpn_lstm_engine_tfmini.bincfg
> > E/native: jni_helper.cc:170 GetContents failed:
> > /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_vision/ocr/data/models/semanticlift_engine_0.2.bincfg
> ```

Can't find any help on it anywhere.